# Select2 Multi Select Remote s.results is not function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im develop web apps that have a form.In that's form, i want to make multi select item with remote data (ajax) because i have more than 1800 data.

Im using Select2 for this. But i got an error when try to make it.

> Uncaught TypeError: s.results is not a function

This is my init code:

```
// ----- DIAGNOSE SELECTION ----- //
var res5 = str.replace("antrian", "diagnosa").replace("periksa", "getData");
$("#diagnosa").select2({
    placeholder: "Ketik untuk mencari diagnosa pasien...",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
        url: res5,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            var results = [];
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                results.push({
                    id: item.kd_diagnosa,
                    text: item.nm_diagnosa
                });
            });
            console.log(results);
            return {
                results: results
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
// ----- DIAGNOSE SELECTION ----- //
```

My select2.js

```
https://jsfiddle.net/22m3tqbf/
```

My select2.css

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fgqontcs/
```

Please help me. If you need any data, i can provide it. Thanks in advanced